# How to force dynamic page instead of webroot file in cakephp Croogo CMS?

Tags: cakephp

I created one dynamic page with slug name as test by using croogo CMS and my webroot contain test.xml.

My url is: http://www.domain.com/test it should redirect to my dynamic page but its showing the content from app/webroot/test.xml.

Please give me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are using Apache and have `MultiViews` turned on.

Add line `Options -MultiViews` to your `webroot/.htaccess`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am facing some other issues related to same, please find below ticket and please guide me on this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917362/croogo-theme-issue-in-localhost-windows