# Croogo Theme issue in localhost [Windows]

Tags: cakephp, croogo

I am using Croogo CMS in my Cakephp website, its working fine in server and all linux machines but it’s not working properly in windows machine. Please find below issue what I am facing in my local host

PHP Version:5.3.13

Croogo Version: 1.4.3

OS: Windows 7 - 32 bit

**Goal:** I want to use my Cakephp default layout instead of croogo theme layout and css and js from croogo theme

Cakephp Layout location: 
app/Views/Layouts/default.ctp

Croogo Theme Layout

```
    Views/Themed/[MyTheme]
                 default.ctp
                 css[folder]
                 js[folder]
```

Now problem is css and images point to this directory theme/[MyTheme]/css/style.css. But this folder structure is not available, so I am getting below error

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localentrust.dev/theme/[MyTheme]/css/style.css"

Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please try to solve this problem or any one want more explanation on this?

Comment: @fahad19 plese help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

probably u have permissions issues, there is no logical reason for your css to not be displayed, the other thing i see is that your default view is not under Layouts folder, and your js and css folders should be under webroot folder. greetings